# Return multiple matches within a string using a regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the following regex to clean up a document that has had apostrophes accidentally replaced with double quotes:

```
([a-zA-Z]\"[a-zA-Z])
```

That find's the first pattern match within the string, but not any subsequent ones. I've used the '*' operator after the group, which I understood would return multiple matches of that pattern, but this returns none. I've tested the regex [here](http://www.regexr.com/) by adding double quotes to the example string.

Does anyone know what the operator I need is for this example?

Thanks

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: @AnandSKumar i'm just testing the above regex at the link given for now.

Comment: if you want all matches you need `findall `, if you are using `search` you will just get the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to turn on global matching, which in Python is done by using [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) instead of `re.search()`. On Regexr, the global flag is enabled like this:

[regex flags menu on top right corner http://puu.sh/kgLFC/5958420d09.png](http://puu.sh/kgLFC/5958420d09.png)

Comment: ah yes, thanks. i havent used regexes for about six months and i appear to have forgotten more than i thought.